# Besides holding up her breasts, what is the use of Hestia's Ribbon?

Tags: danmachi-memoria-freese

I was awarded Hestia's Ribbon when I started the game and it is just sitting in my Special Inventory. However, I haven't found anywhere to exchange it yet.

Anyone know what it can be used for?

Comment: Why the downvotes? If you don't play the game please don't vote.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing as of now many people are saying it’s going to be added later, when she gets added as an adventurer and it would be her amor equipment.

Comment: Do you have any references or links or other info for this?